# proper way of extending ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, observer-pattern, extending

I have extended the `ActiveRecord::Base` class in the following way:

- I made a directory under the `lib`, let's call it now `foo`
- wrote the module which provides the extra method `has_many_bidirectional` to have  bidirectional has_many relationships in `ActiveRecord::Base` classes
- in the `lib/foo/active_record.rb`:

  ```
  module Foo
    module ActiveRecord
      autoload :Associations, 'active_record/associations'
      autoload :Base, 'active_record/base'
    end
  end
  ```
- in the `lib/foo/active_record/base.rb`:

  ```
  module Foo
    module ActiveRecord
      module Base
        def self.included(base)
          base.class_eval do
            include Associations
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
  ```
- and of course the real code in `lib/foo/active_record/associations.rb`:

  ```
  module Foo
    module ActiveRecord
      module Associations

        def self.included(base)
          base.extend(ClassMethods)
        end

        module ClassMethods
          def has_many_bidirectional(...)
            # ...
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
  ```
- extended the `ActiveRecord::Base` class in the `config/environment.rb` with the following code at the end of the configuration file:

  ```
  ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
    include Foo::ActiveRecord::Base
  end
  ```
- with this way Rails was properly included my module, and I could use it without any problem
- until I wanted to **observe** an extended class, because in the `config/environment.rb` the `config.active_record.observers` part is *before* the extending part, and the observable class does not know anything about the new method at that point.

The following error produced:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:1998:in `method_missing': undefined method `has_many_bidirectional' for #<Class:0x1032f2fc0> (NoMethodError)
        from .../app/models/user.rb:27
```

My question is, which is the correct way to extend the `ActiveRecord::Base` class? (I don't want to use callback methods in my `User` class.)

Do I really have to create a *gem* instead of a module under the `lib` directory to have this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `has_many_bidirectional` for ?

Comment: for bidirectional connections between models (for e.g. friendships)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I digged it out, the best way is to create a plugin with the generator:

```
./script/generate plugin has_many_bidirectional
```

And with this way Rails will include it before the observer part. A good tutorial can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#add-an-acts-as-method-to-active-record).

All of my previous code can be easily adopted to this way.

Comment: The tutorial link is no longer available, at least to me.  As near as I can figure out by examining the link, this is a reference to the Book "Rails Cookbook" by Rob Orsini, chapter 14 "Extending Rails with Plug-ins", section "Extending Active Record with acts_as".